# Displaying 1 particular image from a list?

Tags: javascript, css, web-scraping

I was checking a website where there was a list of people with different nationality 
I inspected the elements because I wanted to download the nationality image for each person

the problem was that the image is not inside an IMG tag where I can just open the src attribute and get the link. I used something like getcomputedstyle(element).backgroundImage... and I got the link that I want, but now I'm facing a different problem which is the image I'm trying to download contains all the flags for every country around the world, and somehow only 1 flag is getting shown for each user in the website

how is that possible? I have never seen anything like this, could someone clarify this process to me too? 
because I want to get the flag for each user, also I'm interested in the technique used

I uploaded the link to https://ibb.co/VxjK66B

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique calls "sprite". A map of images in one pig peace. By using it like background-image we can manipulate with background-position to move image in a small area. The size of a block - one flag size in this case. Each country has different background-position values.

You can read more about sprites here:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've never heard about this, but ill for sure check it out